# html2canvas and jspdf is not working with mat-select multiple option

Tags: jspdf, html2canvas, jspdf-autotable

[image: Current result]

```
downloadPdf() {

    var element = document.querySelector('.myTable');

    html2canvas(document.querySelector('.myTable')).then((canvas) => {

      var imgData = canvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg', 1.0);

      var doc = new jspdf.jsPDF('p', 'pt', [canvas.width, canvas.height]);

      doc.addImage(imgData, 0, 0,canvas.width, canvas.height);

      doc.save('DailyStatusReport.pdf');

    });

  }
```

[image: expected result]here I used mat-select but if try to make pdf with jspdf and html2canvas then I am getting only a dropdown icon in mat-option instead of the selected value.

here I used .myTable as a div class of HTML page under this I have mat-select. I tried with getElementById('myTable') also but getting same result and here #myTable as an Id of div

Answer (score 0):

Just add something like this to your CSS-file ( I am using Angular with SCSS )

```
::ng-deep * .mat-select-value {
    max-width: 200px; // any size > 0
  }
```